# Can't install signed manually release Xamarin apk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When I compile in release, archive and sign an apk in my xamarin project I've got the message "Can't install" when I'm trying to install, but If I check and configure in the project options the sign android apk option then the apk size is bigger and the installation is done.

¿What is the difference between these two scenarios?

[image: size apk]

[image: Sign android package image]

Comment: You need to distribute it also. Otherwise that APK is not correctly packed.

Comment: Yes, in both scenarios I distribute the apk.

Comment: @David Did you solved the issue?

Comment: @David I faced similar issue few days ago. The message showed in my phone during installation is "App not installed".   I tried to add  android:extractNativeLibs="true"   in application tag inside my android manifest. And the release APK worked. You can give a try

Comment: The default value for extractNativeLibs its true. @Anand I solved the issue settiong the android package sign values, making visual studio do the sign in the archive process, but can't see the difference when I sign after the archive.

Comment: @David Glad you solved

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sign apk from Android properties project. The steps you should follow are:

1. Compile solution in Release
2. Over Android project, select "Archive" (Archivar)
3. When Archive ends, select archive item, and in bottom rigth click on "Distribute" (Distribuir)
4. I supose you want install manually, click con "Ad hoc" button
5. Now you need to select your Key store (see next step)
6. From these point, you should follow the steps in the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows)

I recommend you, make a backup of these Key store, because, when you make an update, you need sign Apk with the same Key. If you'll use diferent Key, you can't update app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm doing these steps, but I have the message "Can't install", however when I configure the sign options in the project It works. There must be a difference but I cannot see.

Comment: Are you update an existing app, o new install?.
And another thing, i can see in your picture, you are using Debug, but you should compile in Release, steeps i write are for Release mode.

Comment: Thanks dcaso, It's a new install, and yes, I compiling in release, the picture are only an example